# CloudWatch Insights Query - How to count distinct messages ending with phrase

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'd like to get the total distinct count of each message in log groups.
The format of the message is: `Total of [n] rows have been loaded to [table_name]`

example message:
@message

- Total of 1234 rows have been loaded to table1
- Total of 14 rows have been loaded to table3
- Total of 345 rows have been loaded to table2
- Total of 864 rows have been loaded to table3

and my expected output would be **3** instead of 4. How can I execute this on my query?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
fields @message
| parse "Table of * rows have been loaded to *" as rows, table_index
| stats count_distinct(table_index)
```

You might have to filter/parse little differently, but this is the general idea.